# Is there any disadvantage of executing a shell script using nohup?

Tags: linux, nohup

To execute a shell script in background and without an interruption, we use `nohup` command. For example:

```
$nohup mytest.sh &
Press ALT
Press Enter
```

Is there any drawback or disadvantage of this `nohup` utility as this is not a UNIX / LINUX inbuilt command?

Comment: Check if using `screen` could be a better alternative for you.

Comment: What @ott-- said. There is also tmux.

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not a UNIX / LINUX inbuilt command"? `nohup` has been part of Unix for four decades. Do you mean that it's not builtin to the shell? … … … … … … And what's the deal with the `ALT` and `Enter`? … … … … And what does this question have to do with Oracle VM Server?

Comment: I would like to know the purpose of "Press ALT"...

Comment: I still don't know why are you guys suggesting terminal multiplexers when he wanted an explanation about the `nohup` disvantages

Comment: @Lambert: I think, ALT and Then Return key is used to move the execution of shell script in background and use the Terminal to execute other command. I may be wrong....

Comment: The `&` (ampersand) character is used to put the process in the background. Using the `ALT` key is not necessary to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **disvantages** of using nohup would be:

- No stdout messages. You will have to follow the `nohup.out` file to check everything your command is doing. This is the place where `nohup` will print things. It is an advantage depending on the point of view.
- No stderr output. You will have to [manually redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820616/redirect-nohups-stderr-to-nohup-out) those messages.

And these two are not drawbacks, but interesting points about `nohup`:

- It's not a builtin command(in case of `bash`), but it makes part of the  [GNU\coreutils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) package. Almost all distributions package it and install as default. More easy to have `nohup` installed on your system than `tmux`, `screen` or another screen multiplexing tool.
- Some shells like `tcsh` have their [own version](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Builtin_commands.html#nohup) of `nohup`. Isn't even a drawback, but you have to be aware of how it works if you are planning to use another *NIX/BSD system.